# Dynamically creating c# statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying accomplish creating a c# statement dynamically to avoid the use of the switch statement shown below. I looked into CodeSnippetStatement class but could not make it work.

dynamic apps;

```
        switch (entity)
        {
            case "entity_1":
                apps = Xrm.Entity_1Set.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(guid));
                break;
            case "entity_2":
                apps = Xrm.Entity_2Set.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(guid));
                break;
            case "entity_3":
                apps = Xrm.Entity_3Set.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(guid));
                break;
```

...

I would like to do something like this (pass entity dynamically into string and convert the statement to execute in run time):

apps = CodeSnippetStatement(String.Format("Xrm.{0}Set.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(guid)", entity) );

Is that possible??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Entity_1Set` is a public property of `Xrm`, you could use reflection:

```
using System.Reflection; // at the top of your code file

var propertyName = "E" + entity.Substring(1) + "Set";
apps = Xrm.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName ).GetValue(Xrm);
```

This will only work if `Xrm` is an instance of a class (not a static class reference).

Note that reflection is slower than direct access of a property. This time cost is not much if you are only doing this occasionally. But inside a loop, it could add up.

Another technique would be to cache your EntitySet instances into a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, EntitySet> entityMappings; // at the top of your class

var xrm = GetXrmFromSomewhere();
entityMappings = new Dictionary<string, EntitySet>
{
    { "entity_1", xrm.Entity_1Set },
    { "entity_2", xrm.Entity_2Set },
    { "entity_3", xrm.Entity_3Set }
};
```

Then you would just need to do:

```
var app = entityMappings[entity].SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(guid));
```